# Why doesn't !-notation (bang-notation) work in Idris REPL?

Tags: monads, idris

I expected this to evaluate to 3, but got an error instead:

```
Idris> :let x = Just 2
Idris> 1 + !x
(input):1:3-4:When checking an application of function Prelude.Interfaces.+:
        Type mismatch between
                Integer (Type of (_bindApp0))
        and
                Maybe b (Expected type)
```

I also tried this without a toplevel binding and got

```
Idris> let y = Just 2 in !y + 1
Maybe b is not a numeric type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in the fact how `!`-notation desugars.

When you write `1 + !x` this basically means `x >>= \x' => 1 + x'`. And this expression doesn't type check.

```
Idris> :let x = Just 2
Idris> x >>= \x' => 1 + x'
(input):1:16-17:When checking an application of function Prelude.Interfaces.+:
        Type mismatch between
                Integer (Type of x')
        and
                Maybe b (Expected type)
```

But this works perfectly:

```
Idris> x >>= \x' => pure (1 + x')
Just 3 : Maybe Integer
```

So you should add `pure` to make things work:

```
Idris> pure (1 + !x)
Just 3 : Maybe Integer
```

Nothing special in *Idris* repl, it is just how type checker works. That's why there is `pure` in `m_add` functions from *Idris* tutorial:

```
m_add : Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
m_add x y = pure (!x + !y)
```

Comment: Thank you, I somehow completely missed `pure`/`return` in the example for !-notation when reading the tutorial.